# Printing values with tabulate in hex

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I've been following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43706325/3418620) to print an array as a nice table. This works except that it prints values in decimal. How do I print values in hex? Here is the code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = ['array #', 'TX', 'RX']
tx_buffer = [0xCA, 0xFE, 0x80, 0x80, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]

rx_buffer = [0]*54

idx = range(0, 54, 1)
table = zip(idx, tx_buffer, rx_buffer)

print("\n")
print(tabulate(table, headers=headers))
print("\n")
```

Comment: `tx_buffer=[hex(i) for i in tx_buffer]` before you zip you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hex` or `format`

```
tx_buffer=[hex(i) for i in tx_buffer] 
             or

tx_buffer=[format(i, '#x') for i in tx_buffer]
```

[hex(x)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex):

> Convert an integer number to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed
> with “0x”

[format(value[, format_spec])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format):

> Convert a value to a “formatted” representation, as controlled by
> format_spec

Output:

```
array #  TX      RX
---------  ----  ----
        0  0XCA     0
        1  0XFE     0
        2  0X80     0
        3  0X80     0
        4  0X0      0
        5  0X0      0
        6  0X0      0
        7  0X0      0
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks!